# Is it possible to remove/disable a value from Kibana Visualization controls?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, kibana-7

[image]

Here I am adding a dropdown in Kibana Visualization "Controls"

When I click on dropdown I get the values present in this field, Is it possible to remove a value or disable it.

[image: I want to remove 04271 from my list]

Example : I want to remove 04271 from my list, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the visualization, you can add a filter to that visualization (just below the search bar, click "Add filter") in order to specifically exclude that value... or any other you might want to exclude in the future.

Comment: I tried doing this, but I am not able to find my field Roll No. in the Edit Filter option.. Could you please comment on this?